# Stack trace running UNIX application

Tags: c++, c, unix, stack-trace

How can I perform a live stack trace on a running UNIX applicaiton, and are there any utilities that are useful in digesting the stack trace once its done?

I'm looking to see if any functions are getting called more often than I would have expected them to be - the application works fine, it just recently slowed down and it doesn't appear that anything else in the system is responsible (no other processes are running with unusual memory/processor usage).

Comment: This can be a bit platform-specific, can you say what platform you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiling tools will show what bits of the program are taking up the CPU time.  If you have to dig deeper, you may need other tooling.  Depending on what species of unix you're after, the tools will vary, as this is sometimes quite platform specific.  [This article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=810274) discusses process monitoring on Linux.  Different versions of unix may have different sets of utilities for functions that have to interact with the kernel (e.g. [Dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) for Solaris).  Some do work across platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an actual profiler on your application? This will help you much more than just a stack trace. Usually you just have to compile your application with profile information. Then you can run it and use the information written to determine in which functions the most time is being spent, number of calls, etc.

Comment: Absolutely.  Check out gprof (http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html)

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I was looking for - though recompiling doesn't solve the live run issue.  I can recompile on another system and run the other one with the profile information at least though, that's a good start.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I perform a live stack trace on a running UNIX applicaiton

`gcore` can be used to grab a core file for a live process. This will give you a snapshot of the stack traces for all threads. This approach may, however, be a little too heavyweight for your needs.

If the suspect functions are system calls, you could try using `strace` to see what's going on.

In any case, I think the first port of call should be a profiler, such as `gprof`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want this at runtime without any debugger involvment. For that you could use glibc's backtrace functions. Documentation [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_665.html) and [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)(assuming Linux) just to get you started. [This Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6391) article might be of help also.

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger may have the functionality to attach to a running process. With `gdb` this looks like

```
$ gdb path/to/exec 1234
```

where 1234 is the PID of the running process.

(But consider those answers that direct you to a profiling utility.)